# Can I automatically wrap HierarchicalDataTemplate items inside of a TreeViewItem?

Tags: c#, .net, wpf, data-binding, treeview

I have a 4-level tree structure, defined by:

```
<HierarchicalDataTemplate DataType="{x:Type src:Level1}" ItemsSource="{Binding Path=Level2Items}">
    <TextBlock Text="{Binding Path=Level1Name}"/>
</HierarchicalDataTemplate>

<HierarchicalDataTemplate DataType="{x:Type src:Level2}" ItemsSource="{Binding Path=Level3Items}">
    <TextBlock Text="{Binding Path=Level2Name}"/>
</HierarchicalDataTemplate>

<HierarchicalDataTemplate DataType="{x:Type src:Level3}" ItemsSource="{Binding Path=Level4Items}">
    <TextBlock Text="{Binding Path=Level3Name}"/>
</HierarchicalDataTemplate>
<DataTemplate DataType="{x:Type src:Level4}">
    <TextBlock Text="{Binding Path=Level4Name}"/>
</DataTemplate>
```

And it works great. The only thing is, I can't programmatically select any of my bound items, because they're not of type TreeViewItem (and therefore don't have the "IsSelected"  property). Is there a way to automatically wrap databound items in a particular container type (in this case: TreeViewItem)?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If your items are in a `TreeView`, they'll be wrapped in a `TreeViewItem` automatically by the `TreeView`'s `ItemContainerGenerator`. You can do something like this to ensure the `IsSelected` property on `TreeViewItem` maps to a property on your data class:

```
<TreeView>
    <TreeView.ItemContainerStyle>
        <Style TargetType="TreeViewItem">
            <Setter Property="IsSelected" Value="{Binding MyIsSelectedProperty}"/>
        </Style>
    </TreeView.ItemContainerStyle>
</TreeView>
```

Comment: Unfortunately, your assumption that bound items will be wrapped automatically inside a TreeViewItem isn't true in my case (for whatever reason). Calling GetType() on the first item in the TreeView's Items collection returns my type, not type "TreeViewItem". Any thoughts? Thanks!!

Comment: The Items collection contains your items as it is supposed to. The visual tree, however, wraps your item in a container. For TreeViews, the container is a TreeViewItem.

Comment: Kent is absolutely correct. Each item is wrapped in an ItemContainer, described by the ItemContainerStyle property. For a TreeView, the default container is a TreeViewItem. Check out Dr WPF's blog post on ItemContainers: http://drwpf.com/blog/Home/tabid/36/EntryID/32/Default.aspx

Comment: You're both right. The following code helps me accomplish what I'm trying to do:

((TreeViewItem)ConfigurationTreeView.ItemContainerGenerator.ContainerFromItem(myItem)).IsSelected = true;

I'll just wrap that mechanism in to a helper function. Thanks again!!